# Google Tag Manager API example throwing "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in console

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-tag-manager

I've taken the code for the 'complete example' from this Google Tag Manager API dcoumentation:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/devguide#example

I changed `TODO` to my Client ID and updated `ACCOUNT_PATH`, `CONTAINER_NAME` and `WORKSPACE_NAME` but when I run it I'm just seeing a blank page with this in the console.

[image: Console error]

What steps am I missing? I'm also running the file on localhost if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because checkAuth() function on line 47 is calling itself in a recursive loop.

I fixed it by changing the name of the calling function-

```
function checkAuthVal(immediate) {
  var authorizeCheckPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      { client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES.join(' '), immediate: immediate },
      resolve);
  });
  authorizeCheckPromise
      .then(handleAuthResult)
      .then(loadTagManagerApi)
      .then(runTagManagerExample)
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('You must authorize any access to the api.');
      });
}

/**
 * Check if current user has authorization for this application.
 */
function checkAuth() {
  checkAuthVal(true);
}
```

This worked!